# The list of acronyms makes a space in the footnote

Tags: footnotes, acronyms

I am having a problem regarding the list of acronyms. Using an acronym in the text creates a footnote. Unfortunately the footnote automatically comes with a space compared to the footnote maually created with `\footnote`.

I would like to have both of the footnotes start without a space. So manually implementing a space like " test" is not what I am looking for.
The following picture shows the difference:

[image]

I would like to have the word "Oberfläche" at the same level as "test".

Here is my minimal sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,footnote]{acronym}
\usepackage{siunitx}    


   \newcommand{\acrounit}[1]{
    \acroextra{
    \hspace{-21mm}\makebox[18mm][l]{\si[per-mode = fraction, fraction-command = \nicefrac]{#1}}
            }
            }
\begin{document}

Text \footnote{test}
Text A \ac{A}
\newpage
   
        
\textbf{Symbol}   \textbf{Einheit} \hspace{2mm} \textbf{Beschreibung}
\begin{acronym}[LONGLONGEST]

    \acro{A}[\ensuremath{A}]{\acrounit{\meter\squared}Oberfläche}  
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Update: I looked through the documentation of the package "acronym" I used but still couldn't find a solution. I think the appearance of the footnote might be defined in that package. Any help is appreciated. Thank's in advance.

Comment: Update: Problem solved, ther was an unneccacery space in the formular...